# getSymbols is throwing could not find function "importDefaults" errror

Tags: quantitative-finance

I am using FinancialInstrument package. When i try to call getSymbols function, i get following error.

> getSymbols("HSI", src='FI', dir=paste0(PROJECT_HOME,"/data/tick"), extension='RData', 
>   +                     split_method='days', from='2014-11-01', days_to_omit="Saturday")

Error in getSymbols.FI(Symbols = "HSI", env = , verbose = FALSE,  : 
  could not find function "importDefaults"

Answer (score 0):

That is because 'quantmod' package, that 'FinancialInstrument' package depends on, excluded from its dependencies 'Defaults' package, which includes 'importDefaults' function. So downloading 'Defaults' package may help, try `library(Defaults)` before running getSymbols.